# Creating a Custom Event

Tags: c#, events

Can a custom event be created for any object method?
To do this do I just use the following syntax?:

```
myObject.myMethod +=new EventHandler(myNameEvent);
```

The following code has prompted this question:

```
   private void btRunProcessAndRefresh_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        myProcess =new Process();
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\ConsoleApplication4.exe";
        myProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(MyProcessExited);
        myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents =true;
        myProcess.SynchronizingObject =this;
        btRunProcessAndRefresh.Enabled =false;
        myProcess.Start();
    }
```

Comment: check out the [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(VS.71).aspx) of events as well

Comment: note that `myProcess.Exited += MyProcessExited;` is enough.

Comment: @Default  ahhhh ....so I could either have `myProcess.Exited +=new EventHandler(MyProcessExited);` OR I could declare the event and then use `myProcess.Exited += MyProcessExited;` ?

Comment: yes, the `new EventHandler()` is redundant.

Comment: dont forget to mark answer asa accpeted if it works for you ...

Comment: @PranayRana ... nice one - I'd forgotten!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes you can do like this :

[Creating advanced C# custom events](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9355/Creating-advanced-C-custom-events)

or

[The Simplest C# Events Example Imaginable](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11541/The-Simplest-C-Events-Example-Imaginable)

```
public class Metronome
{
    public event TickHandler Tick;
    public EventArgs e = null;
    public delegate void TickHandler(Metronome m, EventArgs e);
    public void Start()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            if (Tick != null)
            {
                Tick(this, e);
            }
        }
    }
}
public class Listener
{
    public void Subscribe(Metronome m)
    {
        m.Tick += new Metronome.TickHandler(HeardIt);
    }

    private void HeardIt(Metronome m, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("HEARD IT");
    }
}
class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Metronome m = new Metronome();
        Listener l = new Listener();
        l.Subscribe(m);
        m.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: that doesn't look like the simplest example to me.

Comment: @Default - check first link having simplest example

Comment: Here's another "as simple as it gets" example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: @PranayRana What is HeardIt?

Comment: @Apalabrados It's a method that's supposed to be in the Listener class, signature private void HeardIt(Metronome m, EventArgs e).  If you follow the second link, it's there. Not sure why it's left out here.

Comment: @Pranay Rana, you are cutting and pasting a code that's incomplete, how can this be the answer the owner selected? Pretty sure the owner didn't understand this code.

Answer (score 45):

Declare the class containing the event:

```
class MyClass {
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;

    public void Method() {
        OnEvent();
    }

    private void OnEvent() {
        if (MyEvent != null) {
            MyEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
myObject.MyEvent += new EventHandler(myObject_MyEvent);
myObject.Method();
```

Comment: Declare public event EventHandler MyEvent = delegate { }; to eliminate the null check.

Answer (score 14):

Yes you can create events on objects, here is an example;

```
public class Foo
{
    public delegate void MyEvent(object sender, object param);
    event MyEvent OnMyEvent;

    public Foo()
    {
        this.OnMyEvent += new MyEvent(Foo_OnMyEvent);
    }

    void Foo_OnMyEvent(object sender, object param)
    {
        if (this.OnMyEvent != null)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }



    void RaiseEvent()
    {
        object param = new object();
        this.OnMyEvent(this,param);
    }
}
```

Comment: I look at some of the other examples provided and they don't include "delegate" - which I've not encountered before

Comment: when you look at the EventHandler, it is just a specific delegate.

Comment: to expound, you should only use a custom event handler delegate if you need different parameters than the ones used for [`EventHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx) or  [`EventHandler<>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x(v=vs.110).aspx).  See [here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, provided you have access to the object definition and can modify it to declare the custom event

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ModelChanged;
```

And normally you'd back this up with a private method used internally to invoke the event:

```
private void OnModelChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    if (ModelChanged != null)
        ModelChanged(this, e);
}
```

Your code simply declares a handler for the declared `myMethod` event (you can also remove the constructor), which would get invoked every time the object triggers the event.

```
myObject.myMethod += myNameEvent;
```

Similarly, you can *detach* a handler using

```
myObject.myMethod -= myNameEvent;
```

Also, you can write your own [subclass of `EventArgs`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Development-Class/SubclassEventArgs.htm) to provide specific data when your event fires.

Answer (score 8):

Based on @ionden's answer, the call to the delegate could be simplified using *null propagation* since C# 6.0.

Your code would simply be:

```
class MyClass {
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;

    public void Method() {
        MyEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
myObject.MyEvent += myObject_MyEvent;
myObject.Method();
```

Comment: And since C# 2.0 you can already simplify to `myObject.MyEvent += myObject_MyEvent` ;)

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare your event in the class from myObject :

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> myMethod; //you should name it as an event, like ObjectChanged.
```

then myNameEvent is the callback to handle the event, and it can be in any other class

Comment: ok but the question has been inspired by some code I'm analysing. I'll add the code to the question. I can't see any declaration.

Comment: Well if you click on go to definition to Exited, it must be an event, and then the handling code is in MyProcessExited.