# Updating Main Window from page in a frame

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm currently developing a WPF application using the MVVM framework. And I have this functionality: [image]

I have a main window which has a combo box and frame (where I put my pages) and a view model. One of the pages in that frame is where a user can add a data and these data are used to populate the combo box in the main window. My problem is how to automatically update the items in the combo box after adding a data from that page. Btw, this page has a different view model too.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your problem not having elements added in your `ComboBox` when you add them in your databounds collection ? If so have you tried using an `ObservableCollection` ?

Comment: Yes. I'm using ObservableCollection in my main window view model. The data are added in a page view model and I can't seem to find a way to also update the main vm.

Comment: Is your problem how you accomplish the connection between the VM of a page in your `frame` and the VM of your main-window ? E.g. `MainWindowVM.AddToComboBox(dataFromPageVM)` ?

Comment: Yes. @Blacktempel

Answer (score 1):

You can establish an event in the page viewmodel for changed data. Then subscribe to those events within the window viewmodel and update the combobox items accordingly.

Comment: Can you give some details on how should I start with events? I'm not really familiar in using them. @grek40

Comment: @HunterWinchester your question doesn't contain any code, so I'm not going to invent any. You can read how to create a very simple event over there for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9885515/5265292

Answer (score 0):

You have access to the parent window from iframe via window.top. You have to write this code in your page what you have loaded in iFrame.

```
window.top.document.getElementById("combobox_element_id").value='Your New Value';
```

best of luck

Comment: OP question is about WPF, not about an HTML/JS web page

Comment: This is a desktop application Mr @Rahul. That won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the Source DataContext of ComboBox (ObservableCollection) to page ViewModel so you can simply modify the collection from Page view model.