# C# Event for changing other fields in Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, events

Im creating dynamic forms in my application.
Im using DevExpress Controls like:

```
            NumericUpDown controlNumUpDown = null;
            DateEdit controlDateEdit = null;
            TextEdit controlTextEdit = null;
            LookUpEdit controlComboBox = null;
            SimpleButton controlButton = null;
            MemoEdit controlMemo = null;
            GridControl controlGrid = null;
            CheckBox controlCheckBox = null;
            CheckedListBoxControl controlCheckedListBoxControl = null;
            RadioGroup controlRadioGroup = null;
            LabelControl controlStaticText = null;
```

Now every control value can rely on another- when the field is visible or not, enabled or not.

So lets say we have date edit (fieldId=48), and a LookUpEdit (combobox).

Now Combobox have defined dynamic list as SQL query like:

`Select * from indexes where inserted_date=Field.48`.

The list of items in combo box should be updated when date in another control changes. Same goes for text editors, if Field.48 would be TextEdit it should work in the same way, same goes for other types of fields given in the code upon.

Take care- its only an example, as i mentioned every control can rely on another, they can even go in infinite loop if user defines it badly (i dont care about that), same as  one field can rely on 100 other fields.

So question is, what event is the best for that ?
So far i have used Leave Event of each control, but it doesnt work, if control is not enabled or not visible.

Sometimes it is required to hide some field, like amountOfDollars (NumericEdit), but still other field like Checkbox (if checked, document is important) may rely on hidden field: amountOfDollars.

Any suggestions? (all answers are welcome, it may be unsolvable by events...)

Comment: I personally don't think any one type of event can do this, because they will vary with type of control, for example for a combo box selectedindexchanged should work, but its not available on other controls unless i'm getting the question wrong, you want to update other controls or make a query when some property of a control is changed

Comment: you got the question right, for other controls (except comboBox,GridView) i want to change values, for ComboBox and GridView i want to change querys.
Yep, you are right, other controls has some specific events, thats why my first though was to use universal event like 'LEAVE', maybe you have some other idea, like some pattern ?

Comment: What I don't understand is how can one edit a disabled/invisible control, and if its value is updated via code then OnLeave(most ui related events) wont be called anyway, anyway I think you try adding a custom event to your all your control that will be called depending on what condition you want here is example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885437/creating-a-custom-event , or may be you can override Onpaint since it will be called every time anything changes on a control

Comment: @Anil onPaint would kill application (as you stated, its being called anytime). I just want to call it on EditValueChanged or TextChanged, but the problem is- when user put first sign (in active control), event is being fired. That also making application working a lot slower.

Comment: Or you can use different event on each control but assign the same function(HANDLER) and a put switch case in handler to decide whats the type of sender control (example if its a checkbox or combo box)  and then accordingly adjust whatever property you to change on other controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't a new concept. You're trying to create a system of **observable properties**--this is the correct approach and design pattern for your requirement.

Google around and also take a look here:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/132577/reactive-properties-for-easy-property-binding

The basic idea is to react not to an event, per se, but to property setter changes for particular controls. Many third-party components expose OnChange-type events for you to intercept particular property changes--others let you override the property-setter behavior. Sometimes you will need to subclass the third-party control and wire-up your own handlers.

Your question is very broad, but the above should help steer you in the right direction even if the referenced link doesn't exactly meet your needs.

Comment: your post moved me to a right direction. I think visitor (a.k.a. observer) pattern, will meet my needs. I shouldnt be focusing on controls at all and their events, instead of that i should bind my objects to controls, and implement them using a pattern.
I was carring too much about controls, they should only change the value of my objects, no matter when, i shouldnt be focusing on that.Thank you.